# How can I set an environment path of Java (jdk) in Linux-KDE?

Tags: linux, kde, java, chrome-book

I´ve installed Linux-KDE on my Chromebook and I managed to install the jdk8 of JAVA, too, however, I don´t know how to set an environment path in this kind of linux-distribution.

How can I do set this?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to be more specific about the linux distribution you installed on chrome book.

Having said that, there are two ways you can perform the required task.

- First is to check the documentation page of your installed linux distribution for JDK installation, because most of the linux distribution offer some kind of package manager which will do the installation and PATH settings for you by default, you do not have to worry about that.
- Second, if you choose to install JDK manually then you have the option to set your JAVA PATH in two ways,

  1. Local(for a particular user)
  2. Global(system-wide for all users)

For the second option visit this official page http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: it was a kde distribution, but crashed. after that, I installed ubuntu 12.04 and began to reinstall all the java stuff necessary for development and went to /etc/profile to set the environment there. then I had to restart the system and check the installation typing "java -version" and "javac -version" in the bash - voila! Turns out it´s working, now! :-)